# functional equation in the set of positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, permutations, contest-math

> Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Find all functions $f :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for any distinct positive integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$, there exists a permutation $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k)$ of $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k\}$ such that
> $f(a_1)/b_1+ f(a_2)/b_2+\ldots+ f(a_k)/b_k$
> is a positive integer.

Please help, I'm really stuck here, I guess $f$ must be constant or linear, I tried induction on $k$, but the permutation mess everything, the case $k=1$ is trivial, idk how to deal with $k>1$.

Comment: Constants don't work.  If $f(n)=c$ for all $n$ then, for large $a$ $\frac {f(a)}a$ is not an integer.  $f(n)=cn$ works for $c\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: More broadly, if, for every $n$ we have $n\,|\,f(n)$ then $f(n)$ works.  thus $f(n)=n^m$ works but so do "piecewise" functions like $f(n)=n^2$ if $n$ is even and $f(n)=n^5$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @lulu and OP I wrote a solution last night but it was messy. Just cleaned it up. Please let me know if you find anything wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: If $p$ is a prime number, $A, B, M \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \nmid B$, $M$ and $p$ are coprime, then the sum $\frac{A}{M} + \frac{B}{p}$ cannot be a positive integer.

Proof of the lemma is straightforward: $\frac{A}{M} + \frac{B}{p}=N \Rightarrow pA + MB=NMp \Rightarrow p | MB$, a contradiction.

Now we prove $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, we must have $n|f(n)$. We construct a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ in the following fashion: $a_1=n$, and $\forall 2\leqslant j \leqslant k$,

$$
a_j > \max\{a_m, f(a_m) , \forall 1\leqslant m<j\}, \text{ and } a_j \text{ is a prime number}.
$$

Then there's a permutation $\{ b_j, 1\leqslant j \leqslant k \}$ of $\{ a_j, 1\leqslant j \leqslant k \}$ such that $S \equiv \sum_{j=1}^k f(a_j)/b_j$ is a positive integer. Assume $b_i = a_k$ for some index $i$, we have

$$
S = \frac{A}{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j} + \frac{f(a_i)}{a_k}.
$$

From the lemma, since $\gcd(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j, a_k)=1$, we know $a_k | f(a_i)$. By construction $a_k > f(a_j), \forall j<k$, therefore $i=k, a_k | f(a_k)$.

It follows that $\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} f(a_j)/b_j$ is also a positive integer. By the same reasoning we have $b_{k-1} = a_{k-1}, a_{k-1} | f(a_{k-1})$. We repeat this process until finally we have $f(n)/n$ as a positive integer.

On the other hand if $n|f(n), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, the identity permutation guarantees that $\sum f(a_j)/a_j$ is a positive integer. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I don't understand "we pick prime number $p_2, p_2, \cdots, p_k$ in the following manner, $p_2>\max (n,f(n))$.  Should the first $p_2$ be a $p_1$?

Comment: No it's $p_2$. The first number is $n$.

Comment: Why does $p_2$ appear twice on your list?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Your goal is to define the numbers $a_i$ and $a_1=n$.  It's confusing to write $p_2, p_2, \cdots, p_k$ though.

Comment: Yes I agree. I want to emphasize all numbers are prime except for $n$. Later I used $a_j$ instead.

Comment: In any case, I think your concept looks good.  I suggest:  Preface your argument by working the case $k=2$ explicitly.  That case is pretty clear and it sets the tone for the general argument.

Comment: I actually first worked out the case $k=2$ but the technique was different. I will work out a better version later. Thanks for your suggestion.